# How to add equivalent symbols to equations

Tags: equations

I am trying to change from [image]

to this
[image]

Here is my code:

```
    \begin{align*}
\smash[b]{\underbrace{\overline{xx\cdots x}}_\text{$2n$}}-\smash[b]{\underbrace{\overline{yy\cdots y}}_\text{$n$}} 
     & = (\overline{\underbrace{zz\cdots z}_{n}})^2  \\
\dfrac{x(10^{2n}-1)}{9} - \dfrac{y(10^n-1)}{9} 
     & = \dfrac{z^2(10^n-1)^2}{9^2}\\9x(10^n+1) - 9y 
     & = z^2(10^n-1)\\9x \cdot 10^n + (9x-9y) 
     & = z^2 \cdot 10^n - z^2 
     \end{align*}
```

Comment: Please, make your code snipped compilable. As it is now, it can produce equation which you show. By the way, is `\Leftrightarrow` what you looking for? Or you like to have `\equiv`?

Comment: @Zarko I am talking about \iff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat*}{4}
&\qquad&
\smash[b]{\underbrace{\overline{xx\cdots x}}_\text{$2n$}}-\smash[b]{\underbrace{\overline{yy\cdots y}}_\text{$n$}} & = (\overline{\underbrace{zz\cdots z}_{n}})^2  \\
\Leftarrow\kern-4pt\Rightarrow&&
\dfrac{x(10^{2n}-1)}{9} - \dfrac{y(10^n-1)}{9} 
     & = \dfrac{z^2(10^n-1)^2}{9^2}\\
\Leftarrow\kern-4pt\Rightarrow&&
9x(10^n+1) - 9y 
     & = z^2(10^n-1)\\
\Leftarrow\kern-4pt\Rightarrow&&
9x \cdot 10^n + (9x-9y) 
     & = z^2 \cdot 10^n - z^2 
     \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As Zarko notes, the `amspackage` also provides a macro `\Leftrightarrow` that is double-headed and double-lined.  It is, however, quite a bit narrower than the self-composed one I provided above with `\Leftarrow\kern-4pt\Rightarrow`.

Comment: Is there special reason that you not use `\Leftrightarrow` as provided by `amsmath` and rather compose it?

Comment: @Zarko I don't use it enough to recall its existence, though perhaps I should edit.

Comment: @Zarko I just took a look, and it looks quite short.  Best I could tell, it was not extensible, either.

Comment: To be honest, I use WinEdt and in similar situations looks in it collected `amsmath simbols :-)

Comment: @Zarko I added a notation to my answer, citing your comment.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You also can try `\ArrowBetweenLines` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

 \begin{alignat*}{2}
 &  &  \smash[b]{\underbrace{\overline{xx\cdots x}}_\text{$2n$}}-\smash[b]{\underbrace{\overline{yy\cdots y}}_\text{$n$}}
     & = (\overline{\underbrace{zz\cdots z}_{n}})^2 \\
\ArrowBetweenLines
 &  & \dfrac{x(10^{2n}-1)}{9} - \dfrac{y(10^n-1)}{9} & = \dfrac{z^2(10^n-1)^2}{9^2}\\%
\ArrowBetweenLines
 &  & 9x(10^n+1) - 9y   & = z^2(10^n-1)\\
\ArrowBetweenLines
 &  & 9x \cdot 10^n + (9x-9y) & = z^2 \cdot 10^n - z^2
 \end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]